# Internet connection activity on Windows 7 (disabling during night)

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, internet, parental-controls

Is it possible to disable internet connection on Windows 7 based on time settings? By either some settings in registry or disabling devices or something similar?

I would like to disable internet connection on my nephew's machine after midnight and until 7am, so he will get some sleep.

There's Thomson's router (SpeedTouch 780 with SW version 6.1.9.6) on the network that I don't think is QoS configurable.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up Parental Controls on Windows 7 based on time of day and block access to IE:

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Set-up-Parental-Controls

Comment: What if the user has other browsers? is it possible to shut down internet access with parental control?

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you do in software, he will get around it. 
Best option is to buy a cheap switch and put an outlet timer on it. His computer is the only thing on the switch. When the timer goes off, the network goes down.
I am guessing his computer is in his bedroom, so put the switch and timer next to the router in another room.

Comment: Starting with Vista, which is the first version of Windows including Parental Controls. you can do use software for control access to the computer, since the control software is integrated with the windows accounts (you can't do much with a computer without an usable login).